# What is the equivalent Python function for "filter" in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab

I want to do apply a `filter` function on a vector in MATLAB.

In Python I write:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = filter(lambda x:x>2,l)
```

How do I write this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent in MATLAB is to use `logical` indexing to filter out elements you don't need:

```
l = [1,2,3,4];
l2 = l(l > 2);
```

What `filter` in Python does is that it returns another list given that the predicate you specify for each element in your list evaluates to `True`.  Any elements that are `False` are removed from the list.  On that same token, in MATLAB, you can directly index into an array with `logical` indexing to give you the same thing.

---

So what exactly does `l2 = l(l > 2);` do?  Basically, `l > 2` gives you an array of `True` and `False` that is the same size as `l`.  It will look like this in MATLAB:

```
>> l = [1,2,3,4]

l =

     1     2     3     4

>> l > 2

ans =

     0     0     1     1
```

As you can see, `l > 2` returns a `logical` vector that is the same size as `l`.  What is shown here is whether or not each value of `l` satisfied the predicate of it being greater than 2.  As expected, the first two elements are `False` while the last two elements are `True`.  By using this `logical` vector as input into your vector `l`, you are **indexing** so that any locations that are equal to `True` in this vector, the corresponding locations in `l` are selected whereas the locations that are `False` get filtered out.  As such, the first two elements are removed because they are  `False` while the last two elements stay because those locations are `True`.

Therefore, doing `l2 = l(l > 2);` thus gives:

```
>> l2 = l(l > 2)

l2 =

     3     4
```

Read more about `logical` indexing here from Steve Eddins's blog: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/

---

## Bonus

However, if you really want to use the `filter` paradigm, you can define a function that can do it like so:

```
function out = filter_python(in, func)
    out = in(func(in));
end
```

This does no error checking and you need to make sure that `func` is a function that accepts a vector and that the output is also a vector as the same size as the input vector `in`.  The function also needs to return `True/False` for each element in the input vector.

Note that I'm calling this `filter_python` because `filter` is a function that already exists in MATLAB that's part of the Signal Processing Toolbox.  Save this to a file called `filter_python.m`.  Now that you're done, you'd call it like this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4];
l2 = filter_python(l, @(x) x > 2);
```

`@(x)` is an anonymous function, much like `lambda x` is in Python.

---

As a bonus, in IPython, this is what we get:

```
In [13]: %paste
l = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = filter(lambda x:x>2,l)

## -- End pasted text --

In [14]: l
Out[14]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [15]: l2
Out[15]: [3, 4]
```

.... and in MATLAB (as we showed earlier):

```
>> l = [1,2,3,4];
>> l2 = l(l > 2);
>> l2

l2 =

     3     4
```

Similarly with the custom function:

```
>> l = [1,2,3,4];
>> l2 = filter_python(l, @(x) x > 2);
>> l2

l2 =

     3     4
```

Comment: `l2 = l(l > 2);` this is really nice.  What to explain how it works?

Comment: @worldterminator - Oh of course.  I thought I already did, but I can be even more verbose.  Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @worldterminator - Have a look!

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also do that sort of thing in python with numpy arrays.

Comment: @TheBlackCat You could, but  that wasn't asked. The question asked how to achieve the same operation in MATLAB.  Even though you can fundamentally replace the `filter` operation with Boolean slicing in `numpy`, what is ultimately desired is perform the same in MATLAB.

Comment: @rayryen: I am aware of that, which is why I submitted it as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: @TheBlackCat - Fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the example (**bonus**) answer of @rayryeng :

> > ```
> > function out = filter_python(in, func)
> >     out = in(func(in));
> > end
> > ```

This idea could be expanded to whole rows of data in a 2D array.

```
function out = filtrow(func,in,colnum)
if nargin == 2
   colnum=0;
   sz = size(in);
   if sz(1)==1 || sz(2)==1
      out = in(func(in));
      return
   else
      out = in;
      for i = sz(2):-1:1
          out = out(func(out(:,i)),:);
      end
   end
end
if nargin == 3
  out = in(func(in(:,colnum)),:);
end
```

Or if you'd prefer by cols.

```
  function out = filtcol(func,in,rownum)
  if nargin == 2
    rownum=0;
    sz = size(in);
    if sz(1)==1 || sz(2)==1
        out = in(func(in));
        return
    else
        out = in';
        for i = sz(2):-1:1
            out = out(func(out(:,i)),:);
        end
        out = out';
    end
  end
  if nargin == 3
    out = in';
    out = out(func(out(:,rownum)),:);
    out = out';
  end
```

So given matrix A:

```
 A =

     0    0.4694    0.1656    0.0838    0.0782    0.8687    0.1818
0.0540         0    0.6020    0.2290    0.4427    0.0844    0.2638
0.5308    0.3371         0    0.9133    0.1067    0.3998    0.1455
0.7792    0.1622    0.6541         0    0.9619    0.2599    0.1361
0.9340    0.7943    0.6892    0.8258    0.0046    0.8001    0.8693
0.1299    0.3112    0.7482    0.5383    0.7749    0.4314    0.5797
0.5688    0.5285    0.4505    0.9961    0.8173    0.9106    0.5499

#%%% We can also remove entire rows or cols by this method
#%%% here we use filtrow to remove rows where elements do no pass the c condition function

>> out = filtrow(@(x) x>0,A)

out =

0.9340    0.7943    0.6892    0.8258    0.0046    0.8001    0.8693
0.1299    0.3112    0.7482    0.5383    0.7749    0.4314    0.5797
0.5688    0.5285    0.4505    0.9961    0.8173    0.9106    0.5499


#%%% Or we can do the same to remove the cols

>> out = filtcol(@(x) x>0,A)

out =

0.0782    0.8687    0.1818
0.4427    0.0844    0.2638
0.1067    0.3998    0.1455
0.9619    0.2599    0.1361
0.0046    0.8001    0.8693
0.7749    0.4314    0.5797
0.8173    0.9106    0.5499

#%%%Or you could filter by individual rows

>> out = filtrow(@(x) x>0,A,1)

out = 

0.0540         0    0.6020    0.2290    0.4427    0.0844    0.2638
0.5308    0.3371         0    0.9133    0.1067    0.3998    0.1455
0.7792    0.1622    0.6541         0    0.9619    0.2599    0.1361
0.9340    0.7943    0.6892    0.8258    0.0046    0.8001    0.8693
0.1299    0.3112    0.7482    0.5383    0.7749    0.4314    0.5797
0.5688    0.5285    0.4505    0.9961    0.8173    0.9106    0.5499
```

Comment: This is a nice attempt, but I really don't like how you're iterating over all of the columns or rows individually. You can do that completely vectorized